# Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm having a problem here i'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

in my pagenation.html

```
<img ng-src="images/left-arrow.png" onclick="page('previous');" style=" float:left; margin-left:10px; width: 7%; height=7%; margin-bottom:10px;"></img>
<img ng-src="images/right-arrow.png" onclick="page('next');" style=" float:left; margin-left:10px; width: 7%; height=7%; margin-bottom:10px;"></img>
```

then my Javascript

```
var page=1;
function page(pcounter)
{
    console.log(pcounter);
   var data_file = "my link";
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   try{
      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
      http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){
      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {
         try{
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
      if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
      {
        // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
        var data = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
              var title=[];
             var date=[];
             var image=[];
             var e;

             if((pcounter=='next') && (pcounter<data.posts))
             {
                 page+=2;
             }
             else if((page!=1)&&(pcounter=='back'))
             {
                  page-=2;
             }

                for (var i in data.posts) {
                    title[i]=data.posts[i].title;
                    date[i]=data.posts[i].date;
                    image[i]= data.posts[i].thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url;
                   }

                 for(var e = page; e < 6; e++){
                     document.getElementById("rtitle" + e).innerHTML=title[e];
                     document.getElementById("rdate" + e).innerHTML=date[e];
                     document.getElementById("rimage" + e).src=image[e];
                 }

      }
   }
   http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
   http_request.send();
}
```

I've tried all the solutions i found here but no luck, anybody had a idea about this?

Comment: change function or variable name, JavaScript [hoist](http://goo.gl/V7PB3W) function and variable and in your case its conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring both a function and a variable named `page`. A function is a variable in JavaScript, so you can't have both with the same name. The variable is overwriting the function, as named functions are hoisted above variables in the JIT compiler, thus causing your error. Just rename one of them and you should be fine.

Something like this (you will also have to change the name anywhere you use it):

```
var pageCount=1;
function page(pcounter)
```

Comment: Came in useful even months later :) I made the same type of mistake.